# Is there a word for weekend/weekday split?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am trying to present a bunch of data using a number of time period splits. For instance, I can present the data by:

1. Day of Week (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, ...)
2. Month (January, February, March, ...)
3. Year (2015, 2016, ...)

I would like to also present a split by weekend and weekday. If I want to split the data by weekend/weekday, is my only option to use that slashed designation of "weekend/weekday?" Or is there a word or phrase that will provide the information without the need for the "\"?

(I am doing this because I can't name files with a "\" in it)

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Not as far as I know.  You may be able to come up with something but i think it would confuse your users, so my advice (as a software engineer & designer) is to not bother and just show the days of the week.

Comment: You're asking for the [hypernym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy) of *weekend* and *weekday*. I don't think there is one. However, since you only have two values, you could treat it as a boolean: *weekday* (true, false). Consider the week to be like a piece of string, with weekends at the ends and weekdays in the middle. One might call each part a *section*. Taking this back to the week, you can have *0. Section/Portion/Part (weekend, weekday)* if you don't mind the generic terms.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I appreciate the feedback. And love the word hypernym!

Answer (score 1):

Why not replace the slash with 'or': "Weekend or Weekday?"

Answer (score 0):

Following from the comment by @Lawrence, to avoid using the slash, perhaps word the title as `Is Workday` or `Is Weekday`, and then have Boolean values in that field.